# How to use sum result of mysql as variable for query

Tags: mysql, sum

I need to the result of my sum query as "variable", is it possible to do that in mysql ?

```
SELECT
  o.employee_id,
  COUNT(o.completion_date),
  SUM(o.qty_passed),
  SUM(o.qty_rejected) AS reject,
  SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN reject >=100
            THEN o.rate * 5000
        ELSE
            0
    END
  ) AS quality_allowance,
FROM
  outputs AS o
WHERE
  `completion_date` BETWEEN '2023-10-22'
  AND '2023-10-26'
GROUP BY
  `o`.`employee_id`;
```

so the reject output will be used for the parameter to calculate the quality_allowance
how to achieve that ?

The result i wanted is not row by row,
it should be sum of all rows for each emoloyee_id that will be used inside the case statement

Comment: If that's a per row calculation, shouldn't the `WHEN` condition be: `WHEN o.qty_rejected >= 100` instead?

Comment: @PaulT. Its for the sum resut of the entire row for each employee_id

Comment: @mandy8055 yess, that help me a lot thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my limited knowledge on MySQL; it does not allow for the reuse of alias names within the same `SELECT` clause where they are defined since `SELECT` clause are evaluated in parallel, not sequentially.

However, one way which I think of to acheive your requirement is that you can use a ***nested subquery***. The outer query can then use the result of the inner query. The inner query calculates `SUM(o.qty_rejected)` AS reject, and the outer query uses this result for further computations. Something like:

```sql
...rest of the query
FROM
(
  SELECT
    o.employee_id,
    COUNT(o.completion_date) AS count_completion_date,
    SUM(o.qty_passed) AS sum_qty_passed,
    SUM(o.qty_rejected) AS reject
  FROM
    outputs AS o
  WHERE
    `completion_date` BETWEEN '2023-10-22' AND '2023-10-26'
  GROUP BY
    `o`.`employee_id`
) AS innerQuery;
```

Here if you notice, the computation of `reject` is done in the inner query, which is then used in the outer query to calculate `quality_allowance`(which you were doing earlier).

***[CODE DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGUpx5QgGRjeYPyCksd5r3/0)***